# stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`<hostname>' did not match expected CN=`smtp-relay.sendinblue.com'

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8

I'm working the mail function in Laravel 8 after I deploy on the live server, I have following configuration.

**.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.sendinblue.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MAIL
MAIL_PASSWORD=*************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**config/mail.php**

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'sendmail'),

'mailers' => 
      [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => env('MAIL_AUTH_MODE'),
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'),
        ],
    ],
```

Am I wrong in my configuration? Any kind of suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

**Note: Everything can be work in local environment (Window 10)**

Answer (score 5):

This error is due to server configuration. The Live Server is configured to restrict outgoing emails from external mail servers.

If you are using WHM/CPanel in your live server,

1. Login to WHM panel and search for smtp and select SMTP restriction.
   [image]
2. Click Disable Button.
   [image]

If you are using any other servers like AWS, DigitalOcean, Google Cloud or any other provider and the configuration depends upon the server.

Comment: So basically this is needed when you're sending the emails through your scripts as the hostname of the provider is included and verified in peer name verifications, so yes this will resolve the issue, I had the same issue and it fixed for me.